# IIS: unable to browse server using host IP address plus Port number different from 80

Tags: windows, iis-7, ip-address, hostname, group-policy

I have an app running in IIS on port 7000. I am able to browse localhost and localhost:7000 but when i change local host to the ip of the computer, I am only able to browse  and not :7000 why is this the case?
I think the solution is [here](https://forums.iis.net/post/2012836.aspx) but i cannot figure out how to get to `local policies on windows 7` and change the required settings. Below is what i get when i browse  with the port.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When i Added  my new application using the IIS Manager, I specified the hostname as localhost. All i had to do was to leave it blank. This setting is similar to the default app in IIS running on port 80